# Trouble with accessibilityservice metadata file [Xamarin Android]

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working on an Accessibility Service for Android in Xamarin.

I am currently trying to replicate this (Java/Android SDK) codelab, but in Xamarin: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/developing-android-a11y-service/#2

Essentially here is my Accessibility Service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android;
using Android.AccessibilityServices;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Views.Accessibility;
using Android.Widget;

namespace AccessibilityServiceTest.Droid.Services
{
    [Service(Label = "Input Utility", Permission = Manifest.Permission.BindAccessibilityService)]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" })]
    [MetaData("android.accessibilityservice", Resource = "@xml/ServiceConfig")]
    public class TapService : AccessibilityService
    {

        public override void OnAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent e)
        {
        }

        public override void OnInterrupt()
        {
        }

        public override bool OnUnbind(Intent intent)
        {
            return base.OnUnbind(intent);
        }

        protected override void OnServiceConnected()
        {
            base.OnServiceConnected();
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my metadata file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
   android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
   android:canPerformGestures="true"
   android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true" />
```

However I cannot find the "xml" folder inside the *Resources* folder of my Xamarin.Android project. This is where the Official Documentation tells me to place my metadata file in (ServiceConfig.xml). I tried making my own xml folder inside the *Resources* folder but it resulted in *failed processing manifest* and *resource xml/ServicConfig not found* errors.

I would find it greatly helpful if someone could tell me where and how I am supposed to place my Metadata file ("ServiceConfig.xml") for my AccessibilityService.

Comment: Can you check your AndroidManifest.xml file that gets generated at compile time? It should be in obj/Debug/Android or somewhere like that. It could be that it is missing some stuff.

Comment: I think this is the relevant bit from the autogenerated file (also I know u from the Xamarin Forum hehe): <service android:label="Input Utility" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" android:name="crc64608a83016c077e5b.TapService">
      <meta-data android:name="android.accessibilityservice" android:resource="@xml/ServiceConfig" />
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>

Comment: Alright, so this is really weird but I made another xml file and put it in the xml folder, (exact same content as before). I named it config.xml instead of ServiceConfig, and then it worked when I used the new one. Still won't work with the old one though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what fixed the error. I added another metadata file (with the same contents as before) but named it different(config.xml in my case), and I used that instead, and it worked. However it still will not work with the old file (ServiceConfig.xml) for some reason.

After adding the new file make sure to edit the attribute to use the name of the new file:

`[MetaData("android.accessibilityservice", Resource = "@xml/config")]`

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I will, but I have to wait 11 hours